# How to check an array includes an ObjectId?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Running the following code:

```js
console.log(typeof req.user.models,typeof req.user.models[0],req.user.models[0] instanceof String,req.user.models[0] instanceof ObjectId,req.user.models)
console.log(typeof req.params.id,req.params.id)
console.log("includes:", req.user.models.includes(req.params.id), req.user.models.includes(ObjectId(req.params.id)))

for(let i=0;i<req.user.models.length;i++) {
  if (req.user.models[i]==req.params.id) {
    console.log("u approx")
    if(req.user.models[i]===req.params.id) {
      console.log("u exact")
    }
  }
  if (req.user.models[i]==ObjectId(req.params.id)) {
    console.log("s approx")
    if(req.user.models[i]===ObjectId(req.params.id)) {
      console.log("s exact")
    }
  }
}
```

prints the following:

```js
object object false true [ 60066eac8a2f2c21f48688f2 ]
string 60066eac8a2f2c21f48688f2
includes: false false
u approx
```

Considering `req.user.models[0] instanceof ObjectId` returns `true`, I do not understand how `req.user.models.includes(ObjectId(req.params.id))` can return `false`, nor how `s approx` and `s exact` cannot be printed.

Also worth noting I encountered some issue using `ObjectId` (or `ObjectID`), my solution being:

```js
const mongo = require("mongodb");
const ObjectId = mongo.ObjectID;
```

Is this perhaps wrong and what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are three ways to solve the problem.

```
 1. req.user.models[i].toString()
 2. JSON.stringify(req.user.models[i])
 3. req.params.id.equals(req.user.models[i])


if (JSON.stringify(req.params.id) === JSON.stringify(req.user.models[i])) {
        console.log('This is true');
}

if (req.params.id.equals(req.user.models[i])) {
    ...
}
```

and you can use this code for search your string id in array of ObjectId

```
const exists = req.user.models.some(val => val.toString() === req.params.id)
```

or

```
const exists = req.user.models.some(val => val.equals(req.params.id))
```

Comment: Neat. I find using `.some()` offers the best flexibility